# How to get the weatherbox from a wikipedia page using the API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

Most of the larger cities have a table with climate data. I think Wikipedia calls them `weatherbox`.

Is there a way to retrieve these tables via the API?

For instance, to get the climate section for NYC I do:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=wikitext&pageid=645042&section=18&format=json
```

I get the text but not the actual table which is referred to as `{{New York City weatherbox}}`.

There seems to be another way to retrieve some weatherboxes but this isn't working for many cities.

This one works:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:New_York_City_weatherbox`

but this one doesn't:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Turin_weatherbox

Comment: Being templates, these weatherboxes are not part of the core Wikimedia names, and are rather user-made content. Given that you further point out there's no standard naming scheme for them, I doubt retrieving them will be as easy as a simple API call. I'd suggest looking at the different names these weatherboxes take, and trying to retrieve them one by one, until one works.